# Fragment transaction animation and actionbar don't go with each other

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've got a problem with fragment transaction. I want to achieve slide on animation, so I created in animator resources objectsAnimators. Problem is only with enter animation, which doesn't work. Exit animation works fine.

There is my code of enter objectAnimator

```
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:propertyName="x"
    android:valueFrom="2000"
    android:valueTo="0"
    android:valueType="floatType" />
```

The exit animation is inverse of this one.

There is my code of creating a transaction

```
UserSettingsFragment conversationsFragment = new UserSettingsFragment();

   FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
       fragmentTransaction
           .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.enter_from_right, R.animator.none, R.animator.none, R.animator.exit_to_right)
           .replace(R.id.messageFragment, conversationsFragment, "settings_fragment")
           .addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

My main activity is AppCompatActivity. All of the fragments are `android.app.Fragment`. When I changed fragments to use support library animations worked, but I wan't able to control actionBar, because it always returned null, so I went back to `android.app.Fragment`.

If you think that using support library will be a better decision, tell me what should I do, to be also able to controll my actionBar. One of my fragments is started from recyclerView Adapter, so there I'm casting to AppCompatActivity, so how it should be changed.

Comment: `I wan't able to control actionBar, because it always returned null` - Why? Are you using `getSupportActionBar()`?

Comment: @Wizard yes I'm using getSupportActionBar, when I used getActionBar it didn't work. I assume that was caused by AppCompatActivity. I'm confused what should I use, support library or standard, to make everything work.

Comment: You should go for support library. Use `getSupportActionBar()` to get Actionbar. `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()` and `support.v4.fragment` instead of `app.Fragment`.

Comment: @Wizard I changed it to use support library, and I can controll ActionBar . But still enter animation doesn't work. Fragment changes actionbar, and after specified time in animation, layout shows up with no animation.